# ORACLE11g autoincrement

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-trigger

> Error code 4098, SQL state 42000: ORA-04098: trigger 'HR.TRGM_ID' is invalid and failed re-validation

I'm getting this problem. What should I do?

```
create table kids(
       id integer primary key, 
       mbrand varchar(100) , 
       mmodel varchar(100), 
       mprice integer,
       mquantity integer,
       mdescription varchar(100),
       mphoto varchar(100)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE  id_seq;

create trigger trgk_id
      before insert on kids
      for each row
    begin
      select id_seq.nextval
        into :new.id
        from dual;
```

Comment: compiled OK for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is simply that your trigger is missing its END statement. Rewrite the trigger as

```
create OR REPLACE trigger trgk_id
      before insert on kids
      for each row
    begin
      select id_seq.nextval
        into :new.id
        from dual;
END TRGK_ID;  -- added
```

and you should be good.

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=677c22b35aadeef54d3aeb322668a560)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you shouldn't do anything. Everything works OK, as far as code you posted is concerned (apart from the fact that `END` is missing).

On the other hand, Oracle complains about trigger whose name is `TRGM_ID`, while the one whose code we have is named `TRGK_ID`. Are we talking about the same trigger?

```
SQL> create table kids(
  2         id integer primary key,
  3         mbrand varchar(100) ,
  4         mmodel varchar(100),
  5         mprice integer,
  6         mquantity integer,
  7         mdescription varchar(100),
  8         mphoto varchar(100)
  9  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE  id_seq;

Sequence created.

SQL> create trigger trgk_id
  2    before insert on kids
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    select id_seq.nextval
  6      into :new.id
  7      from dual;
  8  end;
  9  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into kids (mbrand) values ('Nike');

1 row created.

SQL> select id, mbrand from kids;

        ID MBRAND
---------- ----------
         1 Nike

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

> For `Oracle11g` no need to use `currval` and `nextval` pseudocolumns
>   within a SQL query statement, rather usable within a PL/SQL
>   expression.

So, avoid using :

```
  select id_seq.nextval
    into :new.id
    from dual;
```

and use directly

`:new.id := id_seq.nextval;`

instead.

*P.S. of course, do the above after fullfilling your main issue of adding an `end` clause at the end of the trigger.*

Answer (score 0):

The error say "TRGM_ID" (with "m"):

```
Error code 4098, SQL state 42000: ORA-04098: trigger 'HR.TRGM_ID' is invalid and failed re-validation
```

Your code say "TRGK_ID" (with "k"):

```
create trigger trgk_id
```

Check "TRGM_ID" code, or try recompile trigger:

```
alter trigger [nameOfTrigger] compile;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Oracle 12c or newer, you could use an identity column instead of manually creating a sequence and trigger.  Much cleaner:

```
create table kids(
       id integer generated always as identity primary key,
       mbrand varchar(100) , 
       mmodel varchar(100), 
       mprice integer,
       mquantity integer,
       mdescription varchar(100),
       mphoto varchar(100)
);
```

https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1

Comment: The OP stated (by the tag) that it is Oracle 11g.